# Rhino variables in JSP

Tags: java, javascript, jsp, rhino

I have this in my jsp:

```
<%
    Scriptable scope = Context.enter().initStandardObjects();
    scope.put( "foo", scope,  Context.toObject( "foo", scope ) );
%>

<script type="text/javascript">
   function doSomething() {
      // this works fine, so I can tell Rhino is working to some extent
      var now = new Packages.java.util.Date();
      alert(now);

      // but this comes back as an undefined variable - why?
      alert(foo);
   }
</script>
```

I'm completely baffled - I thought that by putting the String value ("foo") in the default scope I'd be able to see it in the javascript context, yet, I cannot. This would make sense to me if it weren't for the fact that the 'now' variable works fine.

Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1):

Nope, can't access it directly.  You have to use JSP tagging to get to it.  Something like <%= foo %>.

There's a tutorial [here](http://www.jsptut.com/Mixing.jsp).

And now I re-read and see you're doing this in a function.  Using the above should still work.  However, it'd probably be a better practice to pass the value into the function and keep the JSP out of your function declaration.